# AngularJS orderBy function being ignored in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

The orderBy function is being completely ignored. I've added a console.log at one point for testing and the function isn't even being called. The data is still displayed but is unordered.

HTML Code

```
<div id="tabs">
    <a ng-repeat="tab in tabs | orderBy:tabordinal" id="tab-{{tab.tab_id}}" class="{{getClasses(tab)}}" ng-click="tabclick(tab)">{{tab.label}}</a>
</div>
```

JS Function

```
$scope.tabordinal = function (tab) {
    return $scope.taborder.indexOf(tab.tab_id);
};
```

Everything else is set up correctly, (i.e. ng-click's work properly, the data is bound properly, and filters are working on the other elements.

Answer (score 4):

A few things...

1. `orderBy` takes a string, or an expression that returns a string. That string should be the name of a property you want to order by on the list of objects you're ordering. So if the objects in your array have properties like `[ { 0: 'foo', 1: 'bar', '2': 'blah' } ]`, then you're good to go, I guess. But I doubt they're structured like that.
2. `orderBy:tabOrdinal()` if your expression is a function, as yours is in the original post, you need that `()`.

Outside of that, if you provide a fiddle, I can give you more help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PHpHS/1/

I added the () for the function, and it's not passing a parameter to the orderby function.

Comment: That's because your fiddle breaks trying to perform an illegal `GET`

Comment: I've removed the illegal get from the fiddle, and now it appears to work properly on the fiddle, however it's still not working on the site.

Comment: Doesn't work on your site, eh? ... Well, I'll send you my contract and bill rates and we'll get started. ;) haha. But in all seriousness, I guess you'll just have to look at the differences between your site and the fiddle and see if you can reconcile it.

Comment: I figured out the problem. I was using version 1.0.0 of Angular, which doesn't support orderBy function (apparently). I switched to the newest version (currently 1.0.3) and the code works now.